# Registrar datos en dos tablas MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Necesito llenar los campos de la TablaA con los datos que tengo en TablaB, en mi codigo PHP realizo un insert a mi TablaB al mismo tiempo mediante otro insert se llenan datos en TablaA pero me quedan 2 registros vacios que quiero llenarlos desde la TablaB.

```
TABLA A                                   
*********************           
Cliente      | Jose                   
---------------------          
Total        | $10                
---------------------
Plazos       |  
---------------------
Autorizacion | 



TablaB
*************************
PLAZOS       | 12
-------------------------
AUTORIZACION | 1234
```

Quiero que los campos Plazos y Autorizacion de tabla A se llenen automaticamente al llenarse en TablaB, utilizo PHP

Comment: Muestra el insert que usas para poder ayudarte. Y si esto tiene que ocurrir cada vez que se inserta un dato en la tabla, sería mejor programar un  `TRIGGER` que lo haga, así no tienes que lanzar dos insert cada vez. Hay otras cosas que deberías controlar, como asegurarte de que no haya duplicados, etc.

Comment: Por favor, modifica la pregunta e incorpora la estructura de la tabla en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar) y así podamos montar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Preferimos enseñarte a pescar que darte peces, si vemos lo que has intentado, podremos ayudarte a mejorar. Aquí se explica mucho mejor: [ask] Bienvendo a [so]